# Adventure suited for a party of thieves and fast talkers?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, game-recommendation, published-adventures

I'm a fan of books like *The Lies of Locke Lamora* and (switching genres) *The Quantum Thief.* I'm curious about Pathfinder adventures (or APs) that would be well suited for a group of sneaky and/or fast talking scoundrels.

The party doesn't exist yet so character level, setting, party size, and most other variables are flexible; I'm just looking for something where creative/sneaky shenanigans can play a large part in the fun, and where a party without any clanky heavy armor won't get smeared.

I'm particularly interested in Pathfinder right now, but recommendations of an awesome adventure that fits that bill from another game system might work as well.

Comment: As this is a [tag:game-recommendation] question, please adhere to both the [FAQ] and the rules for subjective questions as outlined in [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) and on [our Meta](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/1071/760).  In particular, all responses should be based on actual experience and contain references and examples whenever possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many Pathfinder APs have strong interpersonal and sneaky elements. They will also have a good number of fights, but that's on you as the GM to dial back (our Pathfinder group long since abandoned XP and just advance as needed, so it makes that super easy).

Council of Thieves (in Egorian in Cheliax) and Second Darkness (criminal underground in Riddleport -> undercover among the drow) are probably your absolute most thief-sneaky-friendly-type APs. Both will have some planned fights/dungeon crawls you'd have to lighten up but otherwise are very intrigue centered.  Carrion Crown (gothic horror) has fights but our party was pretty good about bypassing several of them through being clever.

Paizo APs have a bit of a repeating theme where the first 1-3 sections are pretty social and could work well with a thief party; usually one of 4 or 5 is just a huge ol' dungeon crawl and 6 is the balls to the wall boss fight. So running parts 1-3 from most of them will be either thief friendly or easy to mod to be thief friendly.  Curse of the Crimson Throne (revolution in Korvosa) and Skull & Shackles (pirates) both have large parts you could use, but more so the earlier rather than later installments. Shattered Star is more dungeon crawls but could be trap-explorer-thief-friendly.

In general the way you'll need to approach this is to read up - the Paizo APs are real good about providing background details on the people, places, and events. If your PCs don't just kick down doors but lurk and observe, if you are doing a good job of DMing in that style they should see plenty of opportunities to kill people in their sleep, avoid straight fights, get leverage points for negotiation, etc.